# Is there a independent JavaScript library for keyboard shortcuts based on data-attributes with support for a CMD+? popup listing them all?

Tags: javascript, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to enrich a web application with accessible keyboard shortcuts based on simple `data`-attributes. In the best case I'd like to include a standalone javascript library that does all the magic including a generated help-popup that can be accessed by `CMD+?` oder `STRG+?` respectively.

For example like this:

```
<button data-accesskey="cmd+f" title="Start a search">Search</button>
```

By pressing `CMD+?` the user shall be presented a centered overlay on the page that lists all defined accesskeys and their description (`title` or a 2nd `data`-attribute).

Before going all in and creating such implementation myself I wanted to check back if there already is something like this.

Comment: Why this single vote for close? Please explain... I did some research but could not find anything close. Most libraries are more complex and none comes with the generated popup.

Comment: Looks like I'll start something based on https://craig.is/killing/mice though...